# Adding code to div clears input val

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a JS function that adds divs of the class `PizzaBox` to an empty div called `PizzaBoxHolder`. Why is it that whenever a new line is created, the user-inputted values in the inputs are replaced with the placeholders? Also, as a side note, should I even be using a place holder for a color input?

```
function newBox
{
    numOfBoxes += 1; //This is a global variable declared elsewhere, other functions use it but only this one modifies it
    var pizzaBoxCode = "<div class = 'PizzaBox'>"
                     + "    <h6>Box number " + numOfBoxes + "</h6>"
                     + "    <p>Color: <input type = 'color' class = 'boxColor' placeholder = '#000000'/></p>"
                     + "    <p>Toppings: <input type = 'text' class = 'toppings' placeholder = 'Anything but anchovies or mushroom! Never anchovies or mushroom!'/></p>"
                     + "</div>";
    var PizzaBoxHolder = document.getElementById("PizzaBoxHolder") //Empty div until this function fills it up
    PizzaBoxHolder.innerHTML += pizzaBoxCode;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ur lacking " next to ur </h6>

Comment: is your code working now?

Comment: Yes but bcuz of Ihan's answer, not this. I code on my computer but use StackOverflow on my phone, so I manually type the code into SO and sometimes make typos that aren't actually in my source code. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: It's because of `PizzaBoxHolder.innerHTML += pizzaBoxCode;`. The += operator grabs the current HTML block out as it appears in the DOM (which will be exactly how it was added originally so therefore it does not include the user added data), appends the value of pizzaBoxCode, and then setts the result back - the result is it wipes out any data the user entered. @Ihan's suggestion is a much better way to add objects to the DOM. I just wanted to explain what was happening more thoroughly.

Comment: Yeah. I'm new to HTML/JS and used to do straight Java, I've carried over a few habits, specifically abusing +=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're currently doing it, is resetting the entire `innerHTML` of your main `PizzaBoxHolder` element. By resetting the HTML, you're losing the current values. If you change the code to create an element, and then call `.appendChild`, it'll work as expected. The reason is, you're only appending a node to the current element.

```
var pizza = document.createElement("div");
pizza.className += "PizzaBox";
pizza.innerHTML = "<h6>Box number " + numOfBoxes + "</h6><p>Color: <input type='color' class='boxColor' placeholder = '#000000'/></p><p>Toppings: <input type='text' class='toppings' placeholder='Anything but anchovies or mushroom! Never anchovies or mushroom!'/></p>";

var PizzaBoxHolder = document.getElementById("PizzaBoxHolder"); 
PizzaBoxHolder.appendChild(pizza);
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08xcz10d/1/).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help